# Disable periodic task execution in Micronaut during unit test

Tags: micronaut

Now I'm disabling periodic tasks by setting of `initialDelay` for each periodic task with value `10h` in an application configuration which is used during unit tests.

Then the annotation for task method is like this:

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = '10s', initialDelay = '${some-domain.periodic-task.initial-delay}')
void periodicTask() {
    // periodic task implementation
}
```

And in *application.yaml* configuration used in unit test is:

```
someDomain:
  periodicTask:
    initialDelay: 10h
```

The question is: **Is there a better way how to disable periodic task execution in Micronaut during unit test?**

Because I feel that my solution is not nice - it's workaround. But I did not find any global setting for that or any specific annotation which can be used in unit test to achieve that etc.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a better way how to disable periodic task execution in
>   Micronaut during unit test?

It really depends on the particulars but one option is to mark the beans which contain the periodic tasks with `@Requires(notEnv="test")`.

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what I was looking for.